# Installing Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 give me lots of : "package did not load correctly"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2015, updates

I installed VS2015 with update 1 on Windows 7 Entreprise English over Visual Studio 2015. The setup result was some error(s). I Restarted my machine and run the setup again. The setup completed successfully.

Note: that I had Resharper installed on first setup and I removed before retry the setup for the second time (which succeeded).

After re-installation, I got many message box with "package did not load correctly".

Example:
[image]

Now my visual Studio 2015 with Update 1 is totally upside down??? I got error message on start (package did not load correctly):

- Python Tools Package
- XamarinShellPackage

And many more when loading a project (package did not load correctly):

- CollaborationPackage
- ...

Any idea on how we can solve that problem???

**Update:** I'm trying now to uninstall and then re-install again with Visual Studio 2015 with Update 1...

**I fixed my problem by uninstalling Visual Studio 2015 completely and re-install VS2015 with Update 1.**

Comment: Have you reported the bug at https://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio ? - If so, add the link to here.

Comment: @Danny Varod, Not yet. I have an emergency, I will do it after. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: try starting visual studio in safemode via "devenv.exe /safemode" and let us know the results.

Comment: @BradleyUffner, in SafeMode, loading is fine. But I got all other package errors when I load a project. Also, the project seams to not be loaded. If the project is loaded, I can't see it.

Comment: Hmm.. not the result I was hoping for.  If things are bad enough that they are fubar in safemode then your only likely recourse is to reinstall (or repair).  If you opt for that route it might be easier on you to grab one of the new installers that already have Update 1 applied to them.

Comment: @BradleyUffner, oops! ... I didn't see the update 1 alone. I installed Visual Studio 2015 with update 1 over Visual Studio 2015. It never complained. I just completed a full uninstall / re-install with success. Everything seems to work fine. (I also made a little Windows Update in between). Thanks a lots.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same. Tried repair, uninstall and reinstall, tried update 1 package, even did multiple system restores and all failed. This is disappointing as I'm a faithful user and don't bash Microsoft, but this is unacceptable. Seems like OS reinstall is my only recourse. Is there a tool to do a full clean uninstall even of vsix packages?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Uninstall and re-install visual studio 2015

Comment: This didn't help me at all

Comment: I fixed my problem by uninstalling Visual Studio 2015 completely and re-install VS2015 with Update 1.

Answer (score 2):

I found this, maybe that can solve your problem:

[Packages not loading after installing visual studio 2015 RTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547947/packages-not-loading-after-installing-visual-studio-2015-rtm)

By 
 Shittu Joseph Olugbenga

> All i did to get it working was to follow this step: 
>   1.Close all instances of Visual Studio
>   2.Delete everything in this folder C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache
>   3.Restart Visual Studio
>
> Though I have not tried this for 2015, I believe this should solve the
>   problem too. To do this for visual studio 2015, 12.0 should be changed
>   to 14.0

Comment: Thanks Louis-Alexandre, I uninstall CS2015 and install it again right now. I will try your suggestion if setup is not working.

Comment: Worked with VS 2017.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do a combination of the other answers, none of which was uninstalling VS

1. I renamed `C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0`
2. started VS2015
3. closed it down
4. did the binding redirect for `System.Collections.Immutable` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/34018770/57883

Then I've been copying the extensions I think are safe over and seeing if projects all still load.

Comment: I already solved my problem by uninstalling VS2015. Perhaps your solution works fine but I can test it because it work fine now. Thanks you very much for trying to help. I wish it would help some other users.

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting the computer. It was what fixed the issue for me (which appeared right after modifying my installation, and I had not restarted the computer).

Comment: Thanks, I do not have the problem anymore. I marked up because you are surely right but I can't verify.

Answer (score 0):

Close Visual Studio
Delete following folder C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\xx.x\ComponentModelCache
and file
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\xx.x\ActivityLog.xml

Restart Visual Studio