# Visual Studio 2015 with Update 2 - 'The Scc Display Information package did not load correctly'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, load, package

Loading a project in Visual Studio 2015 with Update 2 (either automatically when VS start or manual load), I receive an error saying:  'The Scc Display Information package did not load correctly'.

[image]

The ActivityLog has:

```
  <entry>
    <record>541</record>
    <time>2016/04/01 13:43:26.048</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>SetSite failed for package [Scc Display Information][An item with the same key has already been added.]:{   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.InternalGetResult(Boolean ignoreUIThreadCheck)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.GetResult()}</description>
    <guid>{D7BB9305-5804-4F92-9CFE-119F4CB0563B}</guid>
    <hr>80070057 - E_INVALIDARG</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>542</record>
    <time>2016/04/01 13:43:26.050</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Scc Display Information]</description>
    <guid>{D7BB9305-5804-4F92-9CFE-119F4CB0563B}</guid>
    <hr>80070057 - E_INVALIDARG</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
  </entry>
```

I installed VS2015 with Update 2 over VS2015 with Update 1. I got the error (package ... did no load correctly).

I uninstalled VS2015 completely.
I reinstalled VS2015 with Update 2 completely. I still have the same problem about 'The Scc Display Information' package did not load correctly'.

**Update** The problem seems similar to the [same problem I had with VS2015 Update 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028662/installing-visual-studio-2015-update-1-give-me-lots-of-package-did-not-load-c). But I think it is not related to NuGet because I have no package with "Scc" in it. I always associated "Scc" with Visual Source Safe (could it be related ?). I suspect the problem come from the registry but I can't figure out where.

I tried both solutions from this [Stack Overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082723/the-provider-package-did-not-load-correctly) without success:

- run the command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
  14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /resetskippkgs"
- Delete folder ComponenModelCache
  (C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\XX\ComponentModelCache)

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I am also having the same issue. and some times after loading the solution the solution explorer stays blank.

Comment: Deleting folder ComponenModelCache solved it for me. I suspect it was caused by installing an update for Intel Parallel Studio.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is caused if you have certain MSSCCI-based SCC providers installed. You can check your registry's HKLM key: `SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\SourceCodeControlProvider`

If this key is present, that's likely causing the problem.

### Proper Fix

Install the fix from [KB3151378](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt695655.aspx).

New installations of VS 2015 Update 2 after 4/11/2016 automatically include this fix and no manual installation of a fix is necessary.

### Old workaround follows

If you don't use any of the SCC providers mentioned there, try renaming the key to `SourceCodeControlProvider_` (added underscore). The package should then load cleanly.

We're working on shipping a fix for VS2015 Update 2 to resolve the issue even while you have MSSCCI-based SCC providers installed.

(Microsoft Employee)

Comment: Big shout out to Danny Perschonok who helped us figure out the root cause.

Comment: Have only two entries here, “Microsoft Visual SourceSafe” and “Microsoft Visual SourceSafe (Internet)”.
How’s that “3rd party”? Both providers are parts of Visual Studio 2008, I keep it because WinCE targets aren’t supported by recent VS versions.

Comment: @Soonts, Just want to say that I had the exact same entries as you. I also though that Visual Source Safe should not ne considered as third party, but Microsoft product instead. I don't understand why Andrew talk about 3rd party? It sounds more a bug in the Update 2 than anything else. But one thing sure, its solution works perfectly !!!

Comment: Correct: It really had nothing to do with third party. Any MSSCCI provider does it. It is a bug in Update 2.

Comment: Same problem but I don't have the key SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\SourceCodeControlProvider in the registry , any other solution?

Comment: @jersiovic, Be Sure to check under: HKLM (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) not HKCU. It would be weird if you don't have anything under that key... ???

Comment: When the fix comes available do we need to remove the underscore again before applying the fix?

Comment: I still don't see a key called SourceCodeControlProvider even in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.

Comment: @HerbalMart I would suggest you remove the workaround when you install the fix but it isn't a requirement.

Comment: That key didn't exist. Final y I solved the issue reinstalling VS

Comment: I had similar issue in VS2015 update 3 (so, this answer is not applicable). I solved it by clearing the `%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache` folder.

Answer (score 1):

I have just fixed this problem with VS2015 on Windows7Pro and I DIDN'T have the `SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\SourceCodeControlProvider` registry key. 
I took [Igor's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1032586/igor) advice and ONLY cleared the `%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache` folder. When VS2015 restarted, the error was gone and VS 'rebuilt the cache'.

Darel

Comment: ...but the problem came back, unfortunately