# Null reference exception when trying to create new project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, adfs

I've been trying to create a new project in Visual Studio 2015 that uses ADFS for authentication (following [this](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/12/use-the-on-premises-organizational-authentication-option-adfs-with-asp-net-in-visual-studio-2013/) example). I add the Authority url and the appid URI and click OK. That seems to work ok, but when the project is created, I get an error that reads: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The project is created, but does not have any of the authentication classes. Other devs in my organization can successfully create projects this way (and I can do it using VS 2013 without getting the same error).

I tried repairing VS 2015 as well as uninstalling and reinstalling. I'm at a loss.

UPDATE: 
In the log file, I see the following entry:

```
  <entry>
    <record>601</record>
    <time>2016/04/07 19:21:02.271</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>SccDisplayInformation.SolutionOptions</source>
    <description>Unable to load solution user option &apos;SccProvider.Solution.LoadCount&apos;</description>
  </entry>
```

I was able to determine that I am the only one running Update 2 and  found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36358630/visual-studio-2015-with-update-2-the-scc-display-information-package-did-not)

I don't see any keys in my registry that are similar to what they mention in the linked question.