# Running Visual Studio15 and Atmel Studio7

Tags: visual-studio-2015, atmelstudio

I'm currently facing a problem trying to run **Visual Studio 15 Enterprise Update 1** and **Atmel Studio 7 Build 634** together on **Windows 10 Education**.

I can open and operate VisualStudio without any problem.

However, when I try to run AtmelStudio, I get multiple **"package not found"** errors, telling me to look into the ActivityLog under "...\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AppEnv\14.0".
Since I don't know how to put the important part into the editor here, I'll give you a link to the file on my dropbox.
[ActivityLog.xml](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s3nbsjgm96s3m60/ActivityLog.xml?dl=0)

I've already tried multiple re-installs, changed the order of installing and looked up a few other threads, that suggested clearing different folders in Local and Roaming, but none of that helped.

Any ideas?

*Edit 12.12.15:*
As Devon1337 suggested, the error is caused due to the update 1 of Visual Studio 15 Enterprise, which by the way is already included in Visual Studio 15 Community.

**Workaround:**

1. Deinstall both
2. Install Atmel Studio 7
3. Install Visual Studio 15 Enterprise afterwards and do not install Update 1 (uncheck it in the install-configurator)

Answer (score 2):

> Download [System.Collections.Immutable version 1.1.36 from nuget](https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/System.Collections.Immutable/1.1.36)
>
> Extract the file (it's a zip file), go to \lib\< name>\ and copy the
>   System.Collections.Immutable.dll file into < studio installation
>   dir >\Extensions\Application

http://www.avrfreaks.net/comment/1731666#comment-1731666

Answer (score 2):

Update March 10, 2016:

Atmel has released an updated version build 790 that seems to have resolved this issue.  You can perform an update from inside Atmel Studio or re-download the installer and reinstall.  The release notes do not indicate this is fixed, but I have confirmed the issue is gone since I did a reinstall.

> This is related to some conflict between VS2015 and Atmel Studio 7.  I
>   didn't have this issue until I updated to VS2015 from 2013.  You have
>   to update a config file under AppData\Local\Atmel\AtmelStudio\7.0. In
>   that config file you will find the setting:
>
> ```
> <dependentAssembly>
>     <assemblyIdentity name="System.Collections.Immutable" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
>     <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.27.0-1.1.65535.65535" newVersion="1.1.37.0"/>
> </dependentAssembly>
> ```
>
> System.Collections.Immutable newVersion should be 1.1.37.0 instead of
>   1.1.36.0.  I had to restart my PC after this change.  Once you load Atmel Studio after a reboot, it will perform some update to the
>   packages.

Comment: BTW, I found where I got this solution.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547947/packages-not-loading-after-installing-visual-studio-2015-rtm