# EF7 Can't create Migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, win-universal-app

I did this tutorial to incloud EF7 SQLite to my UWP app: http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/platforms/uwp/getting-started.html

But with the latest EF and EF.Commands version: 7.0.0-rc1-final.

Now I tried to create my first migration with this command in the package-manager-console:

```
Add-Migration MyFirstMigration
```

But I get this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Collections.Immutable,
>   Version=1.1.36.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)

How can I fix that?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2784

Comment: This issue is closed with beta 7 so I'm not sure how relevant this is in rc1-final. Unfortunately the hints in the discussion doesn't seem to work in my case.

Comment: Maybe a Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547947/packages-not-loading-after-installing-visual-studio-2015-rtm/32764073

Comment: I tried the solutions mentioned in the article you've linked but without luck.

Comment: Have you seen this blog https://sergeytihon.wordpress.com/2015/12/01/how-to-restore-viual-studio-2015-after-update-1-dependency-dance/

Comment: @puzzler Thanks for the link. I tried it out but without success..