# Error Resolving dll Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core-rc2

I have updated to dotnet core and vs 2015 update 3 using the installers in the link below.

https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows

After restarting my PC and opening VS I get a compiler error

```
 Version for package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools` could not be resolved   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets  262 5
```

Comment: Have you removed RC1?

Comment: Yes it was removed during the installation.I did not have to remove it manually.

Comment: Have you tried all these suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547947/packages-not-loading-after-installing-visual-studio-2015-rtm

Comment: What version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools are you using?