# Visual Studio 2015 WindowsForms Application could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-forms-designer

I try to start new project and I got this error message

Message

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Any solution? I tried updating, modifying Visual Studio, changing some code in app.config which I googled, but so far no solution. Wherever I want to open the Form1.cs I got the message. Btw I can shut down VS without a problem, I read some had that problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. After a while I've realized that was due to package 'Code Analysis Package' failed to load. I used an advice from "[Packages not loading after installing visual studio 2015 RTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547947/packages-not-loading-after-installing-visual-studio-2015-rtm)" to clear contents of "ComponentModelCache" folder. And that was it.