# Visual Studio 2017 installed without some packages

Tags: .net, visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2017

I installed Visual Studio 2017 community vesion on Windows 7. Installation is completed, but when i start it, some errors, like on picture, appear many times. There is message "Package ExtensionManagerPackage haven't downloaded correctly".

[image]

I tried to uninstall everything about VS, and repeat installation after Windows Update.
Also I tried to install it for other users on my PC.

But the same errors happen.

There is only one error message in ActivityLog.xml

> SetSite failed for package [ExtensionManagerPackage]Source: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.Implementation' Description: Не удалось загрузить тип "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.IOleMenuCommand" из сборки "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". System.TypeLoadException: Не удалось загрузить тип "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.IOleMenuCommand" из сборки "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". в Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.VSPackage.ExtensionManagerPackage.d__27.MoveNext() в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine) в Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.VSPackage.ExtensionManagerPackage.InitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, IProgress`1 progress) в Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.AsyncPackage.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<b__1>d.MoveNext() --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение --- в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() в Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.RethrowException(AggregateException e) в Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.InternalGetResult(Boolean ignoreUIThreadCheck) в Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.GetResult()

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Packages not loading after installing visual studio 2015 RTM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547947/packages-not-loading-after-installing-visual-studio-2015-rtm)

Comment: Thanks you, but i've just tried this tips from this thread, but it didn't help me, unfortunetly. maybe somebody had this problem excactly with VS2017, because content of folder AppData is different on my computer.

Comment: @IvanRomanov, did you meet any error or warning message during the installation of VS 2017? You can use http://aka.ms/vscollect to gather the installation logs. After using it, you will find vslogs.zip under %temp% folder then upload the file to https://onedrive.live.com/ and share the link here.

Comment: Also you can check this site => (VS Developer Community)
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html

Answer (score 0):

As I see no better way, I would try an offline installation of all packages.
(You could try to just get a basic set + maybe "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VisualStudioExtension", if this package is making problems (?).) But I would try to download all. Is about 20 GB (!) for one language..

First get all packages by:

**vs_enterprise__873301792.1489161815.exe --layout %CD%\vs2017offline --lang en-US**

or a similar line (change to the language, you want).

I got exactly 1901 files with this.

After downloading start the .exe inside the vs2017offline directory.