# Strange Visual Studio Installation/Registry bug

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

After updating my windows 10 computer to the latest patch on 5/9, I tried opening a project I had been working on for about 2 months now. VS said it was "unsupported", and popped up with a bunch of failed to load packages. This caught me completely off guard. So following this I tried to see if I could create a new project and move the source files over. No template files would load, and I was unable to create /any/ project. I repaired VS twice, then uninstalled the 2015 version. I then installed the newly released 2017 version. The problem still persisted. How could I fix this? I've tried the `devenv /installvstemplates`
and `devenv /resetsettings`
or any other devenv command. Also deleted the %APPDATA% subfolder holding visual studio's temp files.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You probably need to install NuGet packages that your project relies upon. It likely has dependencies that are not part of a standard install. Can't say for sure, as you didn't show us the exact error messages that you're getting. (Actually, I just saw the [c++] tag, as opposed to the C# implied by your user name. That makes NuGet packages a less likely theory, and the "packages" part of the error message even more strange.)

Comment: In this instance I am using C++,

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/oKhye

http://imgur.com/a/sw6hE
and
http://imgur.com/a/OyCpO

happens when trying to open a project (that I have been working on for about a month now.)

Comment: Hmm, this question seems to be identical, going to follow the directions and keep you updated.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547947/packages-not-loading-after-installing-visual-studio-2015-rtm