# Visual Studio 2015 doesn't load after PC restart

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build

I have been using VS2015 professional for about a year now but I had a power failure on my PC and after restarting VS2015 fails to run.

The startup logo appears for about a second and then disappears.

On the command line:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC>devenv /setup

Package 'Async Query Service Package' failed to load.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC>
```

The problem seems to be Async Query Service Package.

In the activitylog.xml file I see error:

```
  <entry>
    <record>5</record>
    <time>2018/03/01 14:48:06.133</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>LegacySitePackage failed for package [Async Query Service Package]Source: &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.14.0&apos; Description: Could not load file or assembly &apos;WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35&apos; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.&#x000D;&#x000A;System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly &apos;WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35&apos; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.&#x000D;&#x000A;File name: &apos;WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35&apos;&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ThreadHelper.SetUIThread()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ServiceProvider.CreateFromSetSite(IServiceProvider sp)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.SetSite(IServiceProvider sp)&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.&#x000D;&#x000A;To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.&#x000D;&#x000A;Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.&#x000D;&#x000A;To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].&#x000D;&#x000A;</description>
    <guid>{DD7B74B5-C1F9-411A-B22E-5E711592BC6B}</guid>
    <hr>80070002</hr>
  </entry>
```

Do I need the Async Query Service Package?  how can I disable it I don't believe I need it.

I only need the C++ language.

I followed pretty much all the advice in this post:

[Packages not loading after installing visual studio 2015 RTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547947/packages-not-loading-after-installing-visual-studio-2015-rtm)

But the basic uninstall and re-install doesn't fix the issue.

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Try starting `Visual Studio Installer` and hit the repair button? Or else just try a complete reinstall that should pretty much fix everything.

Comment: @Neijwiert Not in my case it didn't

Comment: Hmm then its really messed up. Can't think of any other proper solutions. I say call it gg and give up the coding life haha :)