# Can't open properties for solution in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

After downloading version 16.8.3 VS started showing me this warning: [image: warning_1] .

My main problem is that I can't open Solution Properties, as it shows me this error: [image: error_1] .

I tried:

1. Deleting everything in `%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16_xxxx\ComponentModelCache` and/or `%appdata%\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0`
2. Deleting `.vs` folder
3. Disabling every installed extension
4. And of course restarting VS after every step but nothing of the above worked.
5. Also tried reading given `.xml` file but it's not readable nor helpful, at least for me.
   Does anyone have an idea what is the problem? Thanks in advance.

Update 1: XML part with error

```xml
<entry>
    <record>583</record>
    <time>2020/12/20 13:48:37.553</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [ErrorListPackage]</description>
    <guid>{4A9B7E50-AA16-11D0-A8C5-00A0C921A4D2}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>584</record>
    <time>2020/12/20 13:48:38.803</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>CreateInstance failed for package [ErrorListPackage]Source: &apos;mscorlib&apos; Description: Could not load file or assembly &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.ErrorListPkg, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos; or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.&#x000D;&#x000A;System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.ErrorListPkg, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos; or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.&#x000D;&#x000A;File name: &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.ErrorListPkg, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos;&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyString, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.&#x000D;&#x000A;To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.&#x000D;&#x000A;Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.&#x000D;&#x000A;To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].&#x000D;&#x000A;</description>
    <guid>{4A9B7E50-AA16-11D0-A8C5-00A0C921A4D2}</guid>
    <hr>80004005 - E_FAIL</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
```

Comment: Maybe [Packages not loading after installing Visual Studio 2015 RTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547947/packages-not-loading-after-installing-visual-studio-2015-rtm) will resolve that.

Comment: share the XML, maybe we can see more details

Comment: @magicandre1981 I updated the post with XML part

Comment: @GeorgeFrias Thanks, I will check it

Comment: the Microsoft.VisualStudio.ErrorListPkg plugin fails to load with System.BadImageFormatException which means mixed 32 and 64 bit DLLs.

Comment: @GeorgeFrias Well his solution is mainly based on deleting everything about VS, which is path that I would like to avoid. Also I checked solution about changing `devenv.exe.config` but I am not completely sure if my file is okay or not. If it could help, I can post that part of file.

Comment: @magicandre1981 And how should I fix that?

Comment: as written in xml, [capture a fusion log](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29374658/1466046) and look which files have wrong cpu architecture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I did eventually was repairing VS from VS installer, took me hour or maybe a little bit more, but certainly more faster than completely reinstalling it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a post reputation to add another comment, I just started using the service again yesterday.

I would create a restore point (or just reinstall VS after if it goes wrong) and use the restore point if something goes wrong.

I really do hope you're using Windows because otherwise that's no good for you because I am only on that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I would like to avoid that solution since I have A LOT of extensions, additions, etc. on VS and it would take me a day or even more to reinstall all that, and well I do not have that time now. I will look at the solution about cpu architecture by @magicandre , and post an update on it, when I catch time, since this is not an urgent issue for me, but it must be solved nevertheless.